# Good javascript practice?

Tags: javascript

```
<input type=”text” value=”click” onclick=”textClicked()”>

<script>
function textClicked() {
    document.write(‘Text clicked’); }
</script>
```

OR

```
<input id=’txt’ type=”text” value=”click”>

<script>
document.getElementById(‘txt’).onclick = function() { document.write('Text clicked'); } 
</script>
```

Which of the above is better design practice? In my opinion it is the first one because of the re-usability it provides for function textClicked().

Thank you.

Comment: The second form does not prevent you from giving the function a name.  You can still write `document.getElementById('txt').onclick = textClicked;`.

Comment: I would prefer the second. Then I can manage all my js from my js file. Say you needed to change the onclick event. Who wants to muck through inline calls?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Which of the above is better design practice?

The second option is better:

- You aren't mixing HTML with JavaScript
- You can include the code from a separate script file

> In my opinion it is the first one because of the re-usability it provides for function `textClicked()`.

As André Caron mentioned in comments, there is nothing preventing you from assigning a value to `onclick` by name:

```
<input id='txt' type="text" value="click">

<script>
document.getElementById('txt').onclick = textClicked;

function textClicked() {
  document.write('Text clicked');
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Surely the 1st one, with good names you can find the section you need much faster and you can reuse it if you need for other events.

Comment: guess this is a personal taste? But Its accepted that mixing HTML/JS should be discouraged. Hence the second one is better.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, let's talk a little bit :)

Actually, all over Software Engineering some of best practices are:

1. [Reusable code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_reuse)
2. [Separation of consern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)

In your case *code reuse* is to use the same code for multiple handlers.
*Separation of concern* is not to mix HTML code and Javascript code, as HTML describes the UI, and Javascript describes actions.

In both your examples you have a little issue.
Let's say, you want assign `function1` to `onclick` of `button1` and `button2`. But tomorrow you need to add some code to `button1` only. In your example, you will need to create some other function. What you could really do, is something like (pseudocode):

```
// Today
document.getElementById("button1").addActionForOnclick(function1);
document.getElementById("button2").addActionForOnclick(function1);

//Tomorrow
document.getElementById("button1").addActionForOnclick(function2);
```

The issue is, that `addActionForOnclick` is browser dependent (`addEventListener` in non-IE, `attachEvent` in IE). What I would suggest and consider as best practice is the use of some [javascript framework](http://speckyboy.com/2008/04/01/top-10-javascript-frameworks-which-do-you-prefer/).

My choice is `jQuery` and your code would look like:

Page:

Javascript (I would use a separate file for scripts):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#txt").click(myTxtClickHandler);
});

function myTxtClickHandler()
{
    document.write('Text clicked');
}
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I wouldn't include a library until I found a use for it.  This single line isn't a use for it :)  jQuery is great, but it is good to know JS (how to crawl) before using JS libraries (how to walk)

Comment: I absolutely agree with you, that a single line is not a use for frameworks. At the same time, I prefer to write the code in efficient and multi-browser way. Seeing the question above, I see, that the author can already "crawl" in searching an element by id ;)

Comment: You haven't referenced `myTxtClickHandler` in `$("#txt").click()` - should be: `$("#txt").click(myTxtClickHandler)`